# .NET Core API Azure B2C authentication configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

[In microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/how-to-secure-a-web-api-built-with-aspnet-core-using-the-azure-ad-b2c/) we can find example for authentication configuration for b2c.

```
  services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
           .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(options =>
  {
      Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options);

      options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
  },
      options => { Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options); });
```

appsettings from where configuration is taken looks like that:

```
 "AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://fabrikamb2c.b2clogin.com",
    "ClientId": "90c0fe63-bcf2-44d5-8fb7-b8bbc0b29dc6",
    "Domain": "fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout/B2C_1_susi_reset_v2",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_susi_reset_v2"
    //"CallbackPath": "/signin/B2C_1_sign_up_in"  // defaults to /signin-oidc
  },
```

1. Why do we do first ***Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options);***  when this options has type JwtBearerOptions which does not match at all with our configuration in app settings?
   (Second appearance  of ***Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options);*** has more sense because options has type MicrosoftIdentityOptions)
2. Where we should define authentication Scope in API in this kind of authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You're right, it doesn't make sense. There is zero overlap between the options specified by the AzureAdB2C configuration section and JwtBearerOptions. You can remove that line as it has no effect on the application.
2. Assuming you want to call a downstream web API with specific scopes, you would do roughly the following:

   ```cs
   .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(...)
   .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
   .AddDownstreamWebApi("serviceName", opt => opt.Scopes = "user.read mail.read")
   ```

   See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-api-call-api-app-configuration?tabs=aspnetcore) for more information.

Comment: The docs are not documenting what to have in the appsettings.json

Answer (score 1):

Don't fully understand the question but the:

Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options); });

is to setup a B2C authentication (as opposed to Azure AD).

There are two separate projects. The scope goes into the ToDoList project not the WebApp project

"Add a section name TodoList in the appsettings.json file and add the keys TodoListScope, TodoListBaseAddress".